# Rigorous definition of tangent space

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am studying manifolds, while my book offers a definition of tangent space I am having problems understanding it, so what is a rigorous definition of tangent space?

Comment: There are multiple rigorous definitions. Which book are you reading?

Comment: Lorin W. Tu An introduction to manifolds Second Edition.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: To improve your question, you should formulate it as a question about the definition that you are reading, asking a question specifically about that definition, and informing us what about that definition you do not understand. As currently written, the best answer to your question is "the definition in your book is a rigorous definition".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to define the tangent space. Here's one:

**As the set of all derivations**. A *derivation* at a point $p$ in a manifold $M$ is a linear map $X:C^{\infty}(M)\to\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the product rule $$X(fg)=f(p)(Xg)+(Xf)g(p)$$ for all functions $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M)$. Then the tangent space $T_{p}M$ is the vector space of all derivations at $p$.

One can also define the tangent space in local coordinates, or via initial tangent vectors. Another good reference to look at is John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd Edition*. Chapter 3 in this book covers several definitions of the tangent space.